# Base64 video encoding - good\bad idea?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, video, base64

I'm working on a mobile front-end project using cordova, and the backend developer i'm working with insists that the media files (images/videos) should be transferred as base64 encoded in json files.

Now, with images it's so far working. Although it freezes the UI for a few seconds, it can be deferred somehow.

The videos however are so far a pain to handle, the length of a single/simple video being transferred is nearly 300,000 in length. It brings my poor laptop through a wild spin, and gets the uri after about 20 seconds of going through the code (and it still not working, and I don't feel like debugging it cause it nearly crashes my laptop with every refresh).

**So my questions are:**

- Is base64 encoding a popular way of transferring media in mobile development?
- And if not, what alternative way would you recommend using to transfer/present these videos?

I should mention though, the videos are meant to be viewed at once by a large number of people (hundreds perhaps), and the other developer says that their servers can't handle such traffic.

Much thanks for any advice, I couldn't find this info nowhere. :)

Comment: base64 is a terrible way of transferring video from a bandwidth and performance perspective, use binary to avoid unpacking overhead.

Comment: Why not utilize one of the many free video hosting sites that provide (an also free) API? Youtube? Vimeo? Flickr? Base64 is not the way to go here, too much data, *especially* for mobile clients.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. I agree, it seems like a terrible way of transferring videos. :) The videos should be for employees only, therefore they want to restrict their access to them. What other alternatives could possibly be out there? Thanks!

Comment: you can serve mp4 files on your intranet on some other page that's behind a login, or use basic auth for the video files themselves, even through apache if nothing fancier.

Comment: That's of course the easiest way and I wish they would go with that, but they don't want to overload the traffic on their servers... Does it make sense or does Base64 actually increases traffic? (cause of it's bigger file size being transferred)

Comment: https://medium.com/@alexcambose/webcam-live-streaming-with-websockets-and-base64-64b1b4992db8

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> [...] the backend developer [...] insists that the media files (images/videos) should be transferred as base64 encoded in json files.

This is a very bad (and silly) idea up-front. You *do not* want to transfer large amount of binary data as strings. Especially not Unicode strings.

Here you need to arm up and convince your backend dev rebel to change his mind with what-ever it takes, play some Biber or Nickelback, or even change his background image to something Hello Kitty, or take a snapshot of his screen, set it as background and hide all the icons and the bar. This should help you changing his mind. If not, place a webasto in his office at max and lock all doors and windows.

> Is base64 encoding a popular way of transferring media in mobile development?

It is popular and has a relative long history and became very common on Usenet and so forth. In those days however, the data amount was very low compared to today as all data where transferred over modems.

However, just because it is popular doesn't mean it is the right tool for everything. It is not very efficient as it require an encoding process which convert three octets into four bytes, causing an addition of 33% to the size.

On top of that: in JavaScript each string char is stored as two bytes due to Unicode char-set so your data is doubled and extended 33%. Your 300 mb data is now 300 x 2 x 1.33 = 798 mb (show that to your backdev! :) as it's a real factor if the servers cannot handle large amount of traffic).

This works fine for smaller files but for larger file as in your example this can cause a significant overhead in both time and memory usage, and of course bandwidth. And of course, on server side you would need to reverse the process with its own overhead.

> And if not, what alternative way would you recommend using to transfer/present these videos?

I would recommend:

- Separate meta-data out as JSON with a *reference* to the data. No binary data in the JSON.
- Transfer the media data itself separately in **native bytes** (ArrayBuffer).
- Send both at the same time to server.

The server then only need to parse the JSON data into edible for the backend, the binary data can go straight to disk.

**Update** I forgot to mention, as Pablo does in his answer, that you can look into streaming the data.

However, streaming is pretty much a synonym with buffering so the *bandwidth* will be about the same, just provided in a more brute-force way (usually UDP versus TCP, ie. loss of packets doesn't break the transfer). Streaming with limit your options more than buffering in the client though.

My 2 cents...

Comment: Thank you for a great answer, I must say the backend dev was left quite speechless hehe. :)

Comment: As mentioned in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46763939/3822526), the 33% overhead argument is invalid, due to the ability to gzip the base64 string fairly trivially.

Answer (score 23):

Not sure why "33% overhead" is always mentioned, when that's complete nonsense. Yes, it does initially roughly add that amount, however there's a little thing called gzip (ever heard of it?). I've done tons of tests and the difference is typically negligible. In fact, sometimes the gzipped base64 string is actually *smaller* than the binary file. Check out this guy's [tests](https://www.davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to/). So please, can we stop spreading absolute fiction.

Base64 is a perfectly acceptable method of retrieving a video. In fact, it works amazing for a private messaging system. For instance, if you were using AWS S3, you could store the files privately so there is no URL.

However, the main disadvantage (imho) of using a gzipped base64 video is that you need to wait for the whole video to load, so pseudo-streaming is out of the question.

Comment: How about if the video is sliced in chunks; for example for real-time video conferencing client web app can capture ~50kb video chunks then it can base64 it and gzip then the web server can broadcast the gzipped base64 image to the consumers/clients. Would something like this work efficiently with base64?

Answer (score 3):

**Base64** is a convenient (but not efficient) way of transferring binary data. It's inefficient because transfer size will be 33% bigger than what you're originally transferring. Si it's not a popular way of transmitting video. If you are planning to stream that video, you should be looking for a established protocol for doing just that.

I would recommend a streaming protocol (there are a lot where you can chose from).

Answer (score 1):

I think is bad idea, video files is large. But you can try with small video files.
Try online encoder https://base64.online/encoders/encode-video-to-base64
There you can convert video to Base64 Data URI, and try to insert in HTML

Result like this:

```
<video controls><source src="data:video/mpeg;base64,AAABuiEAAQALgBexAAABuwAMgBexBeH/wMAg4ODgAAA..."></video>
```