# How to save and download file like video file in raw data from postman by post method

Tags: laravel, api, postman

I have used base64_decode to convert string to video file. But its very time consuming and lengthy process and it make postman app very slow.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Can you post a bit more about your question? What you tried etc See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: why dont you send it as a binary file directly ?

Comment: I have used base_64 encode decode for this, and its working

Comment: $video = base64_decode($video_64); //actual image
       $video_url = "video_".time().".mp4";
       if(isset($video) && isset($video_url))
       {
        file_put_contents(public_path().'/videos/'.$video_url, $video);
        $video_path = $video_url;
       }

Comment: But its affecting postman app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at this link:
[Base64 video encoding - good\bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269831/base64-video-encoding-good-bad-idea)

In short, using base64 alone for video transfer is not good for performance and bandwidth. To overcome this issue you have two options:

**First option:**

compress the base64 using gzip as suggested by @D-Marc in the mintioned link to reduce it's size. However, this will add th headache of compressing and decompressing on each request.

**Second option:**

use binary format for the video upload which is more concise and will save you a lot of headache. Which is best described by the chosen answer in the mentioned link.